# How to add motion to parallax layer without being effected by player moment? e.g cloud in back ground

Tags: parallax, godot, gdscript

I'm working on 2D plaformer game which have three parallax layer (sky,mountains and cloud) sky and mountain layer moves according to motion scale property of parallax layer, and i have added a script to cloud layer so it keep moving in one direction i.e right to left even when player is idle or not moving.But i'm stuck with a problem that when the player moves or jumps, cloud also gets the jump effect and keeps following the player. How to make cloud move in one direction irrespective of player moment? 
my cloud script:

```
extends ParallaxBackground

var dst = 0

func _ready():
    set_process(true)
    pass 

func _process(delta):
    dst -= 50 *delta
    set_scroll_offset(Vector2(dst,0))
```

[image: this is image for reference]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming in a game such as this, you have the camera attached to the player, so it can follow the player movement. Is it possible that you have made the cloud a child of either the camera or the player? As far as I understand, parallax backgrounds in side-scrolling games are structured thusly:

```
Node2D
 |_ParallaxBackground    #Base background layer 
 | |_Sprite
 | |_ParallaxLayer        # Middle-back layer (moves at own speed - defined by you)
 | | |_Sprite
 | |_ParallaxLayer2        # Middle-Fore layer (moves at own speed - defined by you)
 | | |_Sprite
 | |_ParallaxLayer3        # Foreground layer (moves at own speed - defined by you)
 |   |_Sprite
 |_KinematicBody2D         #Player Physics/movement
   |_CollisionShape2D      #player collision
   | |_Sprite              #Player image
   |_Camera2D              #camera attached to player (follows player movement)
```

As you can see from this structure, the parallax layers (and their movements) are kept separate from the player/camera. You should be able to control the speed of all the parallax layers separately (including the cloud layer) without any of them being affected by player movement.

I will be the first to admit, I am no expert as I am rather new to Godot, I am simply trying to offer helpful suggestions despite my less-than-complete knowledge of the engine. That being said, please let me know if this solution works for you, as that knowledge will help to fortify my understanding of Godot and improve my ability to help others.